# Drag and Drop for Kendo Angular TreeView

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-treeview

I know the Kendo Angular treeview doesn't support the drag and drop as of now. Is there any other way I can use the drag and drop functionality using jquery or javascript for the Angular kendo treeview?